# STUFF only unique values along with sorting another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to combine values with comma-separated. For that used `stuff`.
But my data has duplicate values, and I just need unique items from that.

Here is a query that I'm using.

```sql
SELECT STUFF
(
    RTRIM
    (
        (   SELECT  N', ' + CAST(column1Name AS varchar(MAX))
            FROM dbo.tableName
            ORDER BY column2Name
            FOR XML PATH (N'') 
        ) 
    )
, 1, 2, N'')
```

I tried `SELECT DISTINCT` within STFF, but that requires a column that used for sorting within SELECT clause, I am using STUFF so I can't use that column in SELECT clause.

```sql
SELECT STUFF
(
    RTRIM
    (
        (   SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + CAST(column1Name AS varchar(MAX))
            FROM dbo.tableName
            ORDER BY column2Name
            FOR XML PATH (N'') 
        ) 
    )
, 1, 2, N'')
```

I also tried to use `sub-query` to do sorting and use distinct outside, but that also gave a compile error.

```sql
SELECT STUFF
(
    RTRIM
    (
        (   SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + CAST(column1Name AS varchar(MAX))
            FROM
            (
                SELECT column1Name
                FROM dbo.tableName
                ORDER BY column2Name
            ) tableAlias
            FOR XML PATH (N'') 
        ) 
    )
, 1, 2, N'')
```

I also tried `GROUP BY`, which also forces me to add column2Name in the SELECT clause.

```sql
SELECT STUFF
(
    RTRIM
    (
        (   SELECT N', ' + CAST(column1Name AS varchar(MAX))
            FROM dbo.tableName
            GROUP BY column1Name
            ORDER BY column2Name
            FOR XML PATH (N'') 
        ) 
    )
, 1, 2, N'')
```

Is there any way to stuff unique values along with sorting based on a different column?

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2017 or later `string_agg()` is easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the `GROUP BY` method. The only thing is when you `GROUP BY column1Name`, there might be multiple value of `column2Name`, so you need to use aggregate on it, example `MIN(column2Name)`

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    RTRIM
    (
        (   SELECT N', ' + CAST(column1Name AS varchar(MAX))
            FROM dbo.tableName
            GROUP BY column1Name
            ORDER BY MIN(column2Name)
            FOR XML PATH (N'') 
        ) 
    )
, 1, 2, N'')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.